# Default gateway is not reachable

Tags: linux, iptables, lxc

I have a vmware player on which i have installed CentOS 6.5. And on that CentOS 6.5 i have installed lxc and on that lxc i have installed centos 6.3.

I am using NAT and bridger as a Network adaptor in vmware player.

My CentOS 6.5 has IP: 192.168.236.140, Gateway: 192.168.236.2

Route on centos 6.5

```
[root@agent1 ~]# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.236.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth1
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0
0.0.0.0         192.168.236.2   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth1
```

Now my Centos 6.3 has IP: 192.168.122.9 and Gateway: 192.168.122.1

route from my centos 6.3 LXC machine

```
[root@agent1vm5 ~]# route -n 
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
0.0.0.0         192.168.122.1   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

Now, the problem is I am able to ping my CentOS 6.5 machine from LXC i.e 192.168.236.140

```
[root@agent1vm5 ~]# ping -c 1 -t 1 192.168.236.140
PING 192.168.236.140 (192.168.236.140) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.236.140: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.037 ms

--- 192.168.236.140 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.037/0.037/0.037/0.000 ms
```

But I am not able to ping the default NAT gateway i.e 192.168.236.2

```
[root@agent1vm5 ~]# ping -c 1 -t 1 192.168.236.2
PING 192.168.236.2 (192.168.236.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.122.1 icmp_seq=1 Time to live exceeded

--- 192.168.236.2 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 received, +1 errors, 100% packet loss, time 0ms
```

So, how can set my routing so that it goes through 192.168.236.2 not from 192.168.122.1.

Comment: Delete the incorrect route in the container.

Answer (score 2):

In your command

```
ping -c 1 -t 1 192.168.236.2
```

You are specifying that the packets are to be send with a TTL of 1. This means they will traverse at most one network hop before producing an error.

In your network configuration your CentOS 6.3 node is not directly connected to the NAT you are trying to reach. The CentOS 6.5 node is between the two. When you try to ping a node two hops away with a TTL of 1, it will not work.

Upon receiving the packet with a TTL of 1, the CentOS 6.5 node sends an ICMP error message back indicating that the TTL has expired. That is working exactly as intended.

Comment: I agree. But what I want is how should I map both the gateways so that my request will go through my default gateway i.e 192.168.236.2

Comment: [root@agent1vm5 ~]# ping 192.168.236.2
PING 192.168.236.2 (192.168.236.2) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 192.168.236.2 ping statistics ---
634 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 634922ms

Comment: Is there any route or rule by which I can achieve this